# Problem with re-enabling disabled Background Agents on Windows Phone 7 Mango

Tags: windows-phone-7, background-agents

I'm working on Windows Phone 7 application using a background-agent to update a Live Tile. The problem I've ran into has to do with disabling and re-enabling the background-agent. Users has the ability to disable background-agents for a specific application under settings (Settings - Applications - Background Tasks).

If the Background Agent is disabled, I get the expected behavior of an InvalidOperationException with the message "*BNS Error: The action is disabled*" if I try to schedule the agent using the following code:

```
ScheduledActionService.LaunchForTest(PeriodicTaskName, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
```

If the user goes back into the settings menu and tick the check box "*Turn background tasks back on for this app the next time I open it*" I still get the same exception.

So my question is how do I execute a task that has been re-enabled?

The [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202944%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) describes the behavior of disabled tasks, but now how to enable them again.

Comment: Just a guess, but did the OS automatically turn the background task back on for you and then did your call fail as it was already enabled?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you shouldn't call `ScheduledActionService.LaunchForTest` outside a debugging scenario.

And secondly, there are only 3 reasons a Scheduled Task can be disabled

1. User disabled it manually
2. The phone ran out of power, and started using Battery Saver. The task will be re-enabled next time you start your application, when there's enough power on.
3. Your Task didn't call `NotifyComplete()`, and as such it was disabled.

In the case of 3. you have to re-create the task. Which usually means the user re-creating the live-tile from your application. Certainly not a recommendation!

So I will suggest you go through your code and ensure that `NotifyComplete()` is **always** called, as well as stop using `ScheduledActionService.LaunchForTest`.

Comment: I know about the LaunchForTest limitation (if not I would have gotten a different Exception than the "BNS Error: The action is disabled".

As I describe in the question this is a case 1 - the user has disabled it, and then later enabled it. So when I enumerate all the tasks I can find it, but the "IsEnabled" flag is set to true (even if the user has clicked to enable the task again).

Comment: So, what's your *actual* problem then?

Comment: Hehe - why IsEnabled is set to false even if the user enables it again under Settings menu.

Comment: Okay. Also, why does it matter? I got tasks generating live tiles, and I've never had to check for IsEnabled.

Comment: Well, it's more that I wan't to understand the intended behavior if a Task has been disabled (and later enabled) as the only way I got it to work now is to remove the task and re-create it (as the existing one won't start up again even if it has been re-enabled in settings)

Comment: Yes, re-create it by attempting to first remove it, and then attempt to create it. This is how I do it: https://github.com/Windcape/DMI-Byvejr/blob/master/DMI.Service/TileGenerator.cs#L161

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3175/discussion-between-claus-jorgensen-and-jonas-folleso)